# Replacing page content using JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a new website using HTML, CSS and a little JavaScript for school and have run into a wall. I am new to website creation and this will be the second website I've built so please bear with me.

My code is as follows:

gd.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./JavaScript/shadowbox/shadowbox.css">
    <script src="./JavaScript/shadowbox/shadowbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">Shadowbox.init();</script>
    <script src="./JavaScript/gdScript.js"></script>
    <title>The Web Page</title>
</head>

<body id="gd">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a id="nav-index" href="index.html"></a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-gd" href="gd.html">Gaming Desktops</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-ws" href="ws.html">Work Stations</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-hd" href="hd.html">Home Desktops</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-ocs" href="ocs.html">Other Computer Sizes</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-gdht" href="gdht.html">Guides and How To's</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-about" href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="main">
        <h1>The Gaming Desktop Page.</h1>
        <p id="question">Firstly are you sure you want to build a full size gaming desktop?</p>
        <br>
        <p id="center">A full sized desktop (ATX) will take up a massive amount of space, about a meter and a half in verticle space! Look at the "Other Computer Sizes" tab if you want something with the same power but much smaller.</p>
        <br><br>
        <div id="options"><button type="button" id="continue" onclick="switchtogames()">Yes</button></div>
            <div id="options">No</div>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id ="footer">
        <h1 id="footer-text">Copyright MystPhysX, 2013</h1>
    </div>        
</body>
```

gd copy.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./JavaScript/gdScript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./JavaScript/shadowbox/shadowbox.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./JavaScript/shadowbox/shadowbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Shadowbox.init();
    </script>
    <title>The Web Page</title>
</head>

<body id="gd">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a id="nav-index" href="index.html"></a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-gd" href="gd.html">Gaming Desktops</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-ws" href="ws.html">Work Stations</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-hd" href="hd.html">Home Desktops</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-ocs" href="ocs.html">Other Computer Sizes</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-gdht" href="gdht.html">Guides and How To's</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-about" href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="main">
        <h1>The Gaming Desktop Page.</h1>
        <p id="question">Okay, time for a quiz!</p>
        <br>
        <p id="center">This quiz will determine what parts I am going to recommend for your new gaming desktop. Please play along for a while!</p>
        <p id="center">Okay first question: <i><b>"What kind of games are you going to play?"</b></i> I need you to answer this question to see what level of graphics you are going to be playing at.</p>
        <br>
        <div id="imageoption">
            <a id="gallery" href="./Images/minecraft3.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Minecraft]"></a>
            <a id="gallery" href="./Images/minecraft2.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Minecraft]"></a>
            <a href="./Images/minecraft1.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Minecraft]">
                <img id="games1" src="./Images/minecraft.png">
                    <p id="gametitle1"><b>Minecraft: </b><i>Low</i></p>
                    <p id="gametext1">
                        <i>
                            Minecraft is a sandbox indie game originally created by Markus "Notch" Persson. The creative and building aspects of Minecraft allow players to build constructions out of textured cubes in a 3D procedurally generated world. Other activities in the game include exploration, gathering resources, crafting, and combat. Minecraft does not require much resources and can be run on the most basic of gaming computers without any worries.
                            <button id="gamechoice" onclick="minecraft()">
                                Choose Minecraft
                            </button>
                        </i>
                    </p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="imageoption">
            <a id="gallery" href="./Images/Borderlands1.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Borderlands 2]"></a>
            <a id="gallery" href="./Images/Borderlands2.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Borderlands 2]"></a>
            <a href="./Images/Borderlands3.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Borderlands 2]">
                <img id="games2" src="./Images/borderlands.png">
                    <p id="gametitle2"><b>Borderlands 2: </b><i>Medium</i></p>
                    <p id="gametext2">
                        <i>
                            Borderlands 2 is an action role-playing first-person shooter ("loot and shoot") video game. It is the sequel to 2009's Borderlands and like the first game, Borderlands 2 players complete a campaign consisting of central quests and optional side-missions as one of four "vault hunters" on the planet Pandora. Key gameplay features from the original game, such as online collaborative campaign gameplay; randomly generated loot, such as weapons and shields are found in Borderlands 2. A mid-range gaming computer will be able to run Borderlands 2.
                            <button id="gamechoice" onclick="borderlands2()">
                                Choose Borderlands 2
                            </button>
                        </i>
                    </p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="imageoption">
            <a id="gallery" href="./Images/Crysis1.png" rel="shadowbox[Crysis 3]"></a>
            <a id="gallery" href="./Images/Crysis2.png" rel="shadowbox[Crysis 3]"></a>
            <a href="./Images/Crysis3.png" rel="shadowbox[Crysis 3]">
                <img id="games1" src="./Images/crysis.png">
                    <p id="gametitle1"><b>Crysis 3: </b><i>High</i></p>
                    <p id="gametext1">
                        <i>
                            Crysis 3 is a first-person shooter video game developed by Crytek running on Cryengine game engine. It is the third main installment of the Crysis series, a sequel to the 2011 video game Crysis 2, and runs on the CryEngine 3 game engine. It was one of the most anticipated upcoming games of 2013. Crysis 3 is one of the most demanding games released this year and will require a very powerful gaming computer to run.
                            <button id="gamechoice" onclick:"crysis3()">
                                Choose Crysis 3
                            </button>
                        </i>
                    </p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id ="footer">
        <h1 id="footer-text">Copyright Elijah, 2013</h1>
    </div>
```

gdScript.js:

```
function switchtogames()
{
    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML= '<h1>The Gaming Desktop Page.</h1>\
    <p id="question">Okay, time for a quiz!</p>\
        <br>\
        <p id="center">This quiz will determine what parts I am going to recommend for your new gaming desktop. Please play along for a while!</p>\
            <p id="center">Okay first question: <i><b>"What kind of games are you going to play?"</b></i> I need you to answer this question to see what level \
            of graphics you are going to be playing at.</p>\
            <br>\
            <div id="imageoption">\
            <a id="gallery" href="./Images/minecraft3.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Minecraft]"></a>\
            <a id="gallery" href="./Images/minecraft2.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Minecraft]"></a>\
            <a href="./Images/minecraft1.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Minecraft]">\
            <img id="games1" src="./Images/minecraft.png">\
            <p id="gametitle1"><b>Minecraft: </b><i>Low</i></p>\
            <p id="gametext1">\
            <i>\
            Minecraft is a sandbox indie game originally created by Markus "Notch" Persson. The creative and building aspects of Minecraft allow players to build constructions out of textured cubes in a 3D\
            procedurally generated world. Other activities in the game include exploration, gathering resources, crafting, and combat. Minecraft does not require much resources and can be run on the most basic \
            of gaming computers without any worries.\
            <button id="gamechoice" onclick="minecraft()">\
            Choose Minecraft\
            </button>\
            </i>\
            </p>\
            </a>\
            </div>\
            <div id="imageoption">\
            <a id="gallery" href="./Images/Borderlands3.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Borderlands 2]"></a>\
            <a id="gallery" href="./Images/Borderlands2.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Borderlands 2]"></a>\
            <a href="./Images/Borderlands1.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Borderlands 2]">\
            <img id="games2" src="./Images/borderlands.png">\
            <p id="gametitle2"><b>Borderlands 2: </b><i>Medium</i></p>\
            <p id="gametext2">\
            <i>\
            Borderlands 2 is an action role-playing first-person shooter ("loot and shoot") video game. It is the sequel to 2009s Borderlands and like the first game, Borderlands 2 players complete a campaign\
            consisting of central quests and optional side-missions as one of four "vault hunters" on the planet Pandora. Key gameplay features from the original game, such as online collaborative campaign\
            gameplay; randomly generated loot, such as weapons and shields are found in Borderlands 2. A mid-range gaming computer will be able to run Borderlands 2.\
            <button id="gamechoice" onclick="borderlands2()">\
            Choose Borderlands 2\
            </button>\
            </i>\
            </p>\
            </a>\
            </div>\
            <div id="imageoption">\
            <a id="gallery" href="./Images/Crysis3.png" rel="shadowbox[Crysis 3]"></a>\
            <a id="gallery" href="./Images/Crysis2.png" rel="shadowbox[Crysis 3]"></a>\
            <a href="./Images/Crysis1.png" rel="shadowbox[Crysis 3]">\
            <img id="games1" src="./Images/crysis.png">\
            <p id="gametitle1"><b>Crysis 3: </b><i>High</i></p>\
            <p id="gametext1">\
            <i>\
            Crysis 3 is a first-person shooter video game developed by Crytek running on Cryengine game engine. It is the third main installment of the Crysis series, a sequel to the 2011 video game Crysis 2, \
    and runs on the CryEngine 3 game engine. It was one of the most anticipated upcoming games of 2013. Crysis 3 is one of the most demanding games released this year and will require a very powerful gaming \
    computer to run.\
            <button id="gamechoice" onclick:"crysis3()">\
            Choose Crysis 3\
            </button>\
            </i>\
            </p>\
            </a>\
            </div>';
}
```

What I'm trying to do is replace the code in gd.html's div#main with the code from gd copy.html's div#main. I'm using a Javascript image gallery called [Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) on my website for a couple images and it works perfectly in gd copy.html but fails to work when I replace the content as described above. The code getting copied over is from gd copy.html (I used it as a template) so I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Please help if you can!

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9eb0li89i54fh7h/k4Q5bVMu4u/Tech%20Website) are all the files if you want them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `!doctype` should be followed by an opening `<html>` tag (though this is unlikely to be the *only* problem).

Comment: Oh wow I can't believe I missed that, thanks! Any idea about the shadowbox problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because when Shadowbox.init() is called it looks for all the rel='shadowbox' elements on the page. Because you are dynamically adding new content you will have to reinitialize shadowbox.

Try this:

```
function switchtogames()
{
    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML= 'your html';
    Shadowbox.setup();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The script fails since you are modify the DOM and Shadowbox.init(); is unaware of the new elements on the page.

Call Shadowbox.init(); after the DOM change is complete.

Comment: Thanks! It worked after I used the code provided by tsanders which basically did as you said.